# single sign on with google auth passport

Tags: node.js, express, single-sign-on, passport.js, passport-google-oauth2

**Short:**

Hi,
I want to do single sign-on with nodejs express passport google oauth

Maybe someone has a good tutorial or sample code

**Long:**

Basically:

1. User goes to my site Login page www.mysite.com/login
2. Click on "Sign In with Google"
3. Passport does the work and the user is logged in

Now up to here everything works fine and 
I have user logged in and they are in session;
I can access with `req.user` but:

4. User goes to another site www.mysite2.com/home

He needs to be already logged in.  But it not working.

Also if I click again on "Sign In with Google" in login page www.mysite.com/login
 the google login page shows again and asks the user to supply email password.

I expect that Google will know that they already authenticated the user
and send me a code (/auth/google/callback?code=4/SwCR3zt89...) 
to my callback route (www.mysite.com/auth/google/callback) for example.

Here is part of the code:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: configService.getGoogleClientId(),
    clientSecret: configService.getGoogleClientSecret(),
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback"
},
 function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
    return done(err, user);
  });
}
));


var app = express();
app.use(session({
  secret: configService.getSessionSecret(),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  //cookie: { secure: true }
}))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: 
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/home');
  });
```

**login.html**:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <a href="/auth/google">Sign In with Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```